# How to approximate derivative inside derivative

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation

I am using a box-scheme for solving partial differential equation. The function is approximated with:
$$
f_p=\psi\cdot\left(\theta\cdot f_{j}^{k+1}+(1-\theta)\cdot f_{j}^{k}  \right) + (1-\psi)\cdot \left(\theta\cdot f_{j+1}^{k+1}+(1-\theta)\cdot f_{j+1}^{k}  \right)
$$
Time derivative is approximated with:
$$
\psi\frac{f_j^{k+1}-f_j^k}{\Delta t}+(1-\psi)\frac{f_{j+1}^{k+1}-f_{j+1}^k}{\Delta t}
$$
Time spatial derivative is approximated with:
$$
(1-\theta)\frac{f_{j+1}^{k}-f_j^k}{\Delta x}+\theta\frac{f_{j+1}^{k+1}-f_{j}^{k+1}}{\Delta x}
$$

My question is how to approximate with box-scheme following PDE:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\sqrt{c-
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}} \right)
$$

I am stuck at that moment at which I approximated the outer spatial derivative:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\sqrt{c-
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}} \right)\approx (1-\theta)\frac{\left(\sqrt{c-
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}} \right)_{j+1}^{k}-\left(\sqrt{c-
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}} \right)_j^k}{\Delta x}+\theta\frac{\left(\sqrt{c-
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}} \right)_{j+1}^{k+1}-\left(\sqrt{c-
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}} \right)_{j}^{k+1}}{\Delta x}
$$
Where:

$c$ - constant,
$t$ - time,
$x$ - spatial variable,
$j$ - space node index,
$k$ - time node index.

What is the best method to approximate the derivatives inside the square root?